# Developing Application on Android - everything works fine I just get popup "android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly"

Tags: android

I am new Android development. I am making an application and everything is going fine. All is working. The only problem is when I run it I get "android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly" popups at ~3 minute intervals. I was wondering if this was just a problem that occurs when your testing. Will I have the same issue if I deploy to Android market? I just don't want users to continuously get this popup when everything seems to be working fine. I've done some searching and it seems that no one else is having this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your adb logcat to see what messages you are getting there?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to debug this. It is not normal. Your app is doing something wrong. Look at the logs in Logcat while running the app on handset, then proceed from there.

Good Luck

Comment: I checked the log. It says I have a RuntimeException. Unable to get provider com.android.providers... does this have anything to do the API level

Comment: You can try posting the stack trace here, that will help us give ideas.